# Question about Microsoft Orleans Dashboard

Tags: orleans

On the "Grains" view of the Orleans Dashboard I see the Labels(?) for Grains. See the red marked part in this picture:

[image]

What does it mean?  If this is some kind of "Label" for the respective Grain, how can I add such a "Label" to my Grain programmatically in my C# code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom labels only by creating your own fork of [OrleansDashboard repository](https://github.com/OrleansContrib/OrleansDashboard) because it's implemented [this way](https://github.com/OrleansContrib/OrleansDashboard/blob/b03518010a3e71a0185fcc247fa49ae0895909f5/App/components/grain-table.jsx#L68):
[image]